# Angular translate - translations in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

i didn't found anything which is good for me how to translate something in controller for example something which i have in array in controller. The issue is that i don't know how to translate title key in features array. Here's the example of array:

```
vm.features = [
            {
                title: "pregled partnera",
                salesbox: true,
                docbox: true,
                connectionbox: true,
                premiumbox: true
            },
            {
                title: "katalog proizvoda",
                salesbox: true,
                docbox: true,
                connectionbox: true,
                premiumbox: true
            },
            {
                title: "ponude",
                salesbox: true,
                docbox: true,
                connectionbox: true,
                premiumbox: true
            }
]
```

So i need title to be translated, also what i have in html is ng-repeat which looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="feature in pricing.features">
    <td>{{feature.title}}</td>
    <td class="text-center salesbox"><span class="icon-checked" ng-if="feature.salesbox == true"></span></td>
    <td class="text-center docbox"><span class="icon-checked" ng-if="feature.docbox == true"></span></td>
    <td class="text-center connectionbox"><span class="icon-checked" ng-if="feature.connectionbox == true"></span></td>
    <td class="text-center premiumbox"><span class="icon-checked" ng-if="feature.premiumbox == true"></span></td>
</tr>
```

How can i translate feature.title? I tried with $filter but i didnt have success.

Also this is my config in angular, which shows that i have external json with all translation keys:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'app/languages/',
    suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('hr');
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
```

Comment: just use `translate` filter: `{{feature.title|translate}}`

Comment: Okay but how i am gonna translate different words in my array? what will be the key? @AlekseyL.

Comment: The key should be in the array (`feature.title` should be the key).

Comment: where is the the `title` translation coming? server or local?